# How to get results of findBySQL

Tags: php, yii

Sorry for my English. Here is a code:

```
public function showLastThreeNews(){
    return News::model()->findBySql('SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 3;');
}
```

Next, for example, I want to get results of the query:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $lastnews = $this->showLastThreeNews();

        foreach ($lastnews as $news){
            ChromePhp::log($lastnews->news_title);
        }

        $this->render('index', array(
            'lastnews'=>$lastnews
        ));
    }
```

Problem is that logger show me one record three times without changing to next record.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Thanks you Rikesh and CORRUPT! It's my inattention

Comment: I change to ChromePhp::log($news->news_title); now i have an error: "Trying to get property of non-object" on this line. What is wrong?

Comment: Is it *not object*? Try to log just `$news` or `ChromePhp::log($news)` to see which type the value is. It might be array, or something else.

Comment: Tried to log ChromePhp::log($news) the result is the attributes values of the record. Why log show me only one record not in loop?

Comment: Well, try to change it to `var_dump($news)` to check is it array or object. If it is an array, then you should use `$news['news_title']` instead of `$news->news_title` to access the values.

Comment: var_dump($news) show  string(1) "1" string(9) "the title" string(11) "the content" string(1) "1" . what is it?

Comment: It is not one of them... Could you please post `var_dump($lastnews);`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30293/discussion-between-oybek-and-corrupt)

Comment: I don't know why, but problem was in findBySQL method. when i changed it to findAllBySQL() problem was solved. Thanks for All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong variable in your loop change it to,

```
foreach ($lastnews as $news){
        ChromePhp::log($news->news_title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
ChromePhp::log($lastnews->news_title);
```

To

```
ChromePhp::log($news->news_title);
```

You have inapropriate usage of `foreach` loop. You are using iteration source instead of current element of `foreach`.